# "solve with" vs "solve for"

Tags: differences, prepositions

I would like to get a clarification whether I do understand and use those two phrases correctly or not.

The context is solving a mathematical problem.

1. *solved with sth* - means a problem is tackled using *sth* method
2. *solved for sth* - means that a problem is transformed in such way that can *sth* can be obtained directly (as in "solve for x")

My question is, am I missing any meanings, or confusing them?

I got confused with the following sentence: "This problem is hard to solve for some methods" which I believe is incorrect, as one should not solve problems to obtain methods but by using them. I tried looking on several online dictionaries to solve + preposition compounds, but I found nothing.

Comment: I think your *hard to solve for* probably represents *hard for some methods to solve* - that is, the *for* phrase modifies *hard* rather than *solve*.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, indeed, the intended meaning is as you describe it. I would like to know if this is correct usage, maybe the difference lies in punctuation. I got quite puzzled. One can of course derive the meaning from the context, but I would like it to be grammatically and syntactically correct.

Comment: It is acceptable in spoken contexts, but should be avoided in written contexts, where the Rule is "Anything which can be misuderstood will be". Point as *is hard to solve, for some methods*, or shuffle as *is hard for some methods to solve* or *is for some methods hard to solve*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with *"This problem is hard to solve for some methods"*. It's the same basic form as...

> [*"It's difficult **for** many algorithms"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Nijinsky%20danced%20Swan%20Lake%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22difficult%20for%20many%20algorithms%22&tbm=bks)

...where we assign a degree of [animacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animacy) to the algorithm, enabling it to face (and either overcome, or be defeated by) difficulties.

Obviously the *method, algorithm, approach* doesn't normally have the autonomy to apply *itself*, so in practice there'll be a person (or at least something more "sentient" than a process) *using* it. But I personally would draw a slight distinction in these cases - if it's *difficult **for** the method*, perhaps it needs a lot of computer resources, or can't handle certain unusual combinations of input data. If it's *difficult **using** the method*, perhaps the researcher has to go to a lot of trouble to apply the method, or is often dissatisfied with the results.

---

OP is perfectly correct that *solve **for** X* means *establish the value of **X*** (using some method which is invariably part of the context (i.e. - ***X*** is an *output*). But *solve **with** X* (or ***using*** X) normally applies where ***X*** is a *method* (or feasibly an *input* value).